# How to include a column containing calculation for a SELECT script?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Just getting my head around PL/SQL.

I wanted to create a SELECT script that will show the difference in date between a start date and an end date and then display a message accordingly within the Flag_Status column.

- If the results from the calculation is 28 days or lower - This should display: "due to expire within the next 28 days".
- If the results from the calculation is more than 28 days - This should display: "due to expire more than 28 days from today".
- Otherwise display: "already expired".

I have tried using CASE, WHEN and THEN statements. I have included the calculation within the CASE functionality, however when ran, I am faced with an invalid identifier error message.

```
SELECT eligible_start, eligible_end,
CASE
WHEN to_date(eligible_end) - to_date(eligible_start) <= 28 THEN "due to expire within the next 28 days"
WHEN to_date(eligible_end) - to_date(eligible_start) > 28 THEN "due to expire more than 28 days from today"
ELSE "already expired"
END AS Flag_Status 
FROM Check_Table
```

I expect the output to show the eligible start date, eligible end date and a column named 'Flag_Status' with the corresponding message.

The output shows an error message "already expired" invalid identifer.

[image: Please see expected results here]

Please could someone advise or offer some tips?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the quick reply! I have edited above and included a link regarding the desired results. I hope this helps.

Comment: One thing to note is that for "due to expire in next 28 days" you shouldn't have "<=28", you should be looking for date differences between 0 and 28 so that the ELSE can capture anything lower than 0.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that you would need to use single quotes instead of double quotes in the output of the `CASE` statements. Single quotes let you define a string, while double quotes are used for identifiers.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    eligible_start, 
    eligible_end,
    CASE
        WHEN TO_DATE(eligible_end) - TO_DATE(eligible_start) <= 28 THEN 'due to expire within the next 28 days'
        WHEN TO_DATE(eligible_end) - TO_DATE(eligible_start) > 28 THEN 'due to expire more than 28 days from today'
        ELSE 'already expired'
    END AS Flag_Status 
FROM Check_Table
```

Other remarks:

- the logic of the `CASE` statement is not very clear; when do you expect `'alreay expired'` to come up? Your sample data does not show that, but you should be aware that, given the current SQL, it will only appear if one of the two date columns is `NULL`, causing the result of the substraction to become `NULL` as well; is this really what you want?
- you seem to be storing dates as strings; this is not a good practice, it would be better to convert those columns to the `DATE` datatype. Else, when using `TO_DATE()`, I would recommend passing the second argument, that represent the NLS format of the string to convert, rather than relying on the database or session defaults